# Removing the default 8px margin from body

Tags: html, css

This question have been asked before I'm aware of, but unfortunately still haven't found a solution. Even though I tried using their solutions.

My problem is that I can't get rid of the default 8px margin on around the body/html tag. It looks like that it doesn't even respond to the changes I put in between the curly brackets.

Html:

```
<div class="header">
 Header123
</div>

<div class="nav">

  <ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>PROJECT</li>

  </ul>

</div>

<div class="main">
  Article
</div>

<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
background-color: blue;
} 

.container
{
margin: 0;
background-color: red;
}

.header
{
 text-align: left;
 height: 90px;
 background-color: green;
 margin: 0;
}

.nav
{
  float: right;
}

.nav ul
{
  list-style: none;
height: 30px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.nav ul li
{
  margin: 10px;
}


.footer
{

 height:40px;
}
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/RasmusGodske/yg2gsa0t/

Answer (score 7):

For HTML:

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
```

For CSS:

```
body {margin:0;padding:0}
```

Probably you are having a difficulty because margin and padding are two different things. You should try both and use the one that suits your needs.

You can read more about margin vs padding from [here](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-margin-vs-padding)

Answer (score 2):

Remember: margin is outside an element's border; padding is inside.

You need to set the padding of the body element to zero. (The margin of the body element is meaningless; it'd represent a space outside the browser window!)

As an aside, you don't need to set any CSS properties on the `html` element. `body` already contains everything that you'd want to set properties on.

Comment: Oh i see what you mean, but i actually just tried that and that didn't work at that time. Just found out what my real problem was, i had this in the start of my CSS file. 
`<style type="text/css">` Apparently that was the problem... I have no idea why though. If you go to the link i had and then just add the padding, you see that it doesn't fix it. You have to remove the style tag aswell

Comment: That wasn't present in your question. Next time, make sure your question accurately reflects the code you're using!

Comment: Srry just found out now. Do you have any idea what that is happening?

Comment: It happened because `<style ..>` was interpreted as the first CSS style instead of an HTML tag which caused a silent error and the first real style in your list was ignored (`body, html`).  You could have pasted that into the HTML area on JS Fiddle and it would've worked correctly.  Just a JS Fiddle issue - too bad they don't strip out the `<style>` and `</style>` tags automatically in the CSS input for that reason.  Except I guess you really don't want inline styles, they should be in external css files.

Comment: Oh that that makes sense, I actually don't think that's just a problem in JS Fiddle cause it does the exact same thing, when I'm testing it on my local computer. By the way do you wanna write that as a answer to the question?

Comment: Regardless of whether his code was right, this answer is very wrong. Only the first line of it is true. The body is an element that can have whatever dimensions you give it. The fact that it can have a margin is demonstrated by the question: it has a margin of 8px by default. The body's size is independent of the window. That's how you get scrollbars.

Comment: To emphasize Jools' point, the Margin of the body element is the distance between the Viewport left-edge, and the body left-edge.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//hh781509(v=vs.85).  The default of 8px is correct for Firefox (72.0.1).  Explicitly setting "style=margin-left:8px" in the body element has the expected effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly remove the margin using:
`body { margin: 0; }`